# $f(x)$ if $f(xy)=f(x) +f(y) +\frac{x+y-1}{xy}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying the functional time $f(xy)=f(x) +f(y) +\frac{x+y-1}{xy} \forall x,y \gt 0 $ and $f'(1)=2$

**My work**

Putting $y=1$

$$f(1)=-1$$
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
But I don't know anything about $f(x+h)$  so what to do in this problem ?

Comment: Hint: The function $g$ defined by $g(t)=f(t)+\frac1t$ satisfies $$g(xy)=g(x)+g(y).$$ Can you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$
yf'(xy)=f'(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2y}
$$
For $y=1/x$, we get
$$
\frac{f'(1)}{x}=f'(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}
$$
so
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{f'(1)-1}{x}
$$

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{f'(1)-1}{x}$

Comment: Is there any general way to do this problem .

Comment: You assumed y as constant

Comment: @AakashKumar Yes, indeed. For a differentiable function this is a path to try.

Comment: @alans Thanks, fixed

Comment: Excellent, well done +1

Comment: Is there some general method to do this tour of problem ? Taking y as constant in generally this type of  problem will hold good or not ?

Comment: @AakashKumar It's a fairly general method, but there's no guarantee it will lead to an easy solution, like here. It should be tried, nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=xy$. Differentiate the given function with respect to $x$:
$$
    y\frac{df(u)}{du}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}+\frac{1}{xy}-\frac{x+y-1}{x^2y}
$$

Then differentiate w.r.t. $y$:
$$
    xy\frac{d^2f(u)}{du^2}+\frac{df(u)}{du}=-\frac{1}{xy^2}-\frac{1}{x^2y}+\frac{x+y-1}{x^2y^2}
$$

The right-hand side simplifies:
$$
    xy\frac{d^2f(u)}{du^2}+\frac{df(u)}{du}=-\frac{1}{x^2y^2}
$$

Substituting $u$ for $xy$:
$$
    u\frac{d^2f(u)}{du^2}+\frac{df(u)}{du}=-\frac{1}{u^2}
$$

Re-writing the left-hand side:
$$
    \frac{d}{du}\left[u\frac{df(u)}{du}\right]=-\frac{1}{u^2}
$$

Integrating and applying the given boundary condition gives:
$$
    u\frac{df(u)}{du}=1+\frac{1}{u}
$$

Integrating again gives:
$$
    f(u)=a+\ln{u}-\frac{1}{u}
$$

This is a solution when $a=0$, so:
$$
    f(x)=\ln{x}-\frac{1}{x}
$$